Appending to Path to Access Parent Directory in PyCharm vs Terminal
Why is it that
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from file_in_parent_dir import a_function

works in PyCharm, but not in when I run the file from CMD or PowerShell?
(Windows 10, Python 11.3.3)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_in_parent_dir'
Instead I have to use
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
from trace_recursion import trace

(which also works on Linux, with "./")
Could someone please explain the difference between the two approaches, and why PyCharm allows the first?

May be related to your problem. Difference is mostly working directory (os.getcwd() to compare), and PYTHONPATH variable, which is being extended with content and source roots (os.getenv('PYTHONPATH') to compare).

From which hierarchy are you running both cases? Modifying sys.path is not recommended.

The difference between insert and append can be found in this question: Effect of using sys.path.insert(0, path) and sys.path.append(path) when loading modules.
The reason why PyCharm might allow the first might be due to using a different interpreter when running your script. It could be that you are running different versions of Python, and you have not installed the module you need in the version that you are using in PowerShell.
Each Python interpreter has its own set of libraries, especially when you have different versions of Python installed. If you install a library, it will be specific to that version and not available to all.
Depending on whether you have more than one version installed, running python3 vs python3.11 in PowerShell could execute different versions.
Here's an example in Ubuntu: You can see that by doing python3 --version, it uses the default one, which is 3.8.10, but there are many more.

To check the Python interpreter in PyCharm, check this official documentation: Configure a system interpreter.
If you are using the same interpreter, another reason might be that PyCharm might be using a virtual environment that has the needed libraries installed there, so when you run from PowerShell, you don’t have those modules which are installed in the virtual environment only.
You can check the how to configure a virtual environment in the official documentation: Configure a virtual environment

It is because of the folder that you import the packages, is not a python package
all the python packages folders have init.py file
first of all create a __init__.py then move the files into it and then your pycharm can recognize the path

what is missed  in the answer above is the underscored before and after the init
it must be like this
init
